# How add new key into array of json hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, hash, grouping

I have a big array like:

```
[
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
...
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
]
```

and I need to add new 'group' key into each hash. First five hashes should have 'group': 1, second five hashes should have 'group': 2 e.g. to get in result array:

```
[
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 1},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 1},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 1},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 1},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 1},
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: 2},
...
{id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs', group: N},
]
```

If I use Array#group_by and Array#each_with_index methods code works slow, cause array have many records... How can I do it using ruby to make code run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your input sample because there was no need for that large of a sample. You can interpolate how to do what you need from this code:

```
require 'json'

foo = [
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
]

foo.each_slice(2).with_index(1){ |a, i| a.each{ |h| h[:group] = i } }
puts foo.to_json
# >> [{"id":1,"name":"abs","surname":"abs","group":1},{"id":1,"name":"abs","surname":"abs","group":1},{"id":1,"name":"abs","surname":"abs","group":2},{"id":1,"name":"abs","surname":"abs","group":2}]
```

Here's what it looks like broken out to be more readable:

```
puts JSON::pretty_generate(foo)
# >> [
# >>   {
# >>     "id": 1,
# >>     "name": "abs",
# >>     "surname": "abs",
# >>     "group": 1
# >>   },
# >>   {
# >>     "id": 1,
# >>     "name": "abs",
# >>     "surname": "abs",
# >>     "group": 1
# >>   },
# >>   {
# >>     "id": 1,
# >>     "name": "abs",
# >>     "surname": "abs",
# >>     "group": 2
# >>   },
# >>   {
# >>     "id": 1,
# >>     "name": "abs",
# >>     "surname": "abs",
# >>     "group": 2
# >>   }
# >> ]
```

Here's what is happening:

- [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) slices up the array into N-sized chunks.

  ```
  pp foo.each_slice(2).to_a
  # >> [[{:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>1},
  # >>   {:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>1}],
  # >>  [{:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>2},
  # >>   {:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>2}]]
  ```
- [`with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) adds an incrementing value to the list of parameters passed into the block. That is being assigned to `i` in the block.

  ```
  pp foo.each_slice(2).with_index(1).to_a
  # >> [[[{:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>1},
  # >>    {:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>1}],
  # >>   1],
  # >>  [[{:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>2},
  # >>    {:id=>1, :name=>"abs", :surname=>"abs", :group=>2}],
  # >>   2]]
  ```

Comment: but I need to have 5 elements in group, so first 5 elements should have "group: 1", next 5 elements should have "group: 2"...

Comment: You can figure that out from the code in the answer.

Comment: I didn't want to give you the *exact* code, because it's important to teach people how to fish, i.e., how to figure this out, rather than give you a fish, i.e., give you the code answering just this question. It's an old-guy thing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
foo = [
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
  {id: 1, name: 'abs', surname: 'abs'},
]
group_count =5

foo.each_with_index do |u,i|
  u['highlight_group'] = i.div( group_count ) 
end

puts foo
```